# Как отслеживать изменения данных бд (SQLite) в python-проекте?

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, pyqt, qsqldatabase

Я пишу программу на python используя PyQt6 и SQLite. Мне надо получать уведомления от бд каждый раз, когда в таблицах происходят изменения. Я пробовал делать следующее:

```
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

db: QSqlDatabase = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE', 'ConnectionName')
db.setDatabaseName('DatabaseName')
db.open()
db.driver().subscribeToNotification('TableName')
```

, но всё, что я получаю - это имя таблицы, сообщение о том, что источник уведомления неизвестен и число (похоже, что это rowid). Во-первых, я бы хотел узнать, действительно ли возвращаемое число является rowid?
Во-вторых, я бы хотел получать ещё тип операции: insert, update или delete. Есть ли возможность получать через PyQt6.QtSql уведомления от SQLite об изменении данных, содержащие тип операции? Если нет, то можно ли это реализовать через библиотеку sqlite3?

**UPD**
Как я понял, реализовать уведомления через встроенную библиотеку sqlite3 нельзя, но есть другие библиотеки, через которые можно. Тем не менее, мне бы очень хотелось сделать это через PyQt. У Qt есть встроенный драйвер для SQLite, поддерживающий уведомления. А ещё Qt позволяет создавать свои драйверы. Предполагаю, что можно добавить во встроенный драйвер получение типа производимых операций или написать свой драйвер с использованием одной из поддерживающих уведомления библиотек. Это реализуемо, как считаете?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872700/sqlite-data-change-notification-callbacks-in-python-or-bash-or-cli

Comment: @СергейКох, спасибо за наводку. Как я понял, использование функции `sqlite3_update_hook`, предназначенной для уведомлений, не доступно в стандартном пакете `sqlite3`. Думаю, что в PyQt и подавно. Не представляю, как интегрировать соединение через `ctypes` в мою программу, но это другой вопрос.

Comment: Есть еще одна чисто "теоретическая" возможность, подключиться к sqlite через библиотеку `APSW`, https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/about.html, в которой поддерживается данная функция. https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/connection.html#apsw.Connection.set_update_hook.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант перевести взаимодействие с БД на ORM, к примеру у SQLAlchemy имеется возможность отлавливать события связанные с БД: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html

Comment: Спасибо, изучу этот вариант.